# wkhtmltopdf -> Java HttpServlet only white page

Tags: java, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I try to serve a HTML page as PDF using wkthmltopdf but I only get a white PDF page as output.

Here is my short snippet inside the doPost method:

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe http://10.80.2.234/details.jsp?99999 -");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

            resp.setContentType("application/pdf");

            int bytes;
            while ((bytes = reader.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes);
            }

            reader.close();
            out.close();
```

Using the 
`c:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe http://10.80.2.234/details.jsp?99999 - > test.pdf` 
from the command line is working just fine.

Thanks in advance for your help.